# How to rename all files in a folder google colab

Tags: linux, unix, google-colaboratory

I have folder names as `out` in google colab.
I want to rename all files in the folder
file name look like

```
name_001_0000_abc.png
name_002_0000_abc.png
name_003_0000_abc.png
```

and I want to rename it to

```
name_001.png
name_002.png
name_003.png
```

I have tried this `!rename 's|.*/_0000_abc||' /out/*`
but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

`rename 's/_0000_abc//' name_*`

Comment: Bareword "_0000_abc" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).

Comment: What is your case ?? Can you clarify ??

Comment: I have a folder with multiple files and I want to remove `_0000_abc` from all files name

Comment: Does it change the name as what you want ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235176/discussion-between-nhatnq-and-talha-anwar).